# Create tuple object from networkx kernighan_lin_bisection

Tags: python, networkx

I need to split a network with `networkx`'s `kernighan_lin_bisection` function but can't initialize the object. I'm embarrassed to say that my toy example below does work:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import community
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 8), (1, 8)])
blocks = community.kernighan_lin.kernighan_lin_bisection(g, partition=None, max_iter=10)
blocks

({3, 4}, {1, 2, 8})
```

However, with my actual data -- a network with 489 nodes and 1832 edges, I can print the resulting tuples from `kernighan_lin_bisection` but not save it as an object. What may the problem be?

Comment: How do you mean save it as an object? Can you give us more code so that we can reproduce the problem? Are you trying to save the tuple to file or what?

Comment: In that I run run object_name = CODE, but then can't retrieve the contents of object_name by running it. When I run just CODE, it prints the expected output, but just can't assign it to an object.

Comment: Please post some code that we can run to find the problem. or post the error message you are getting

Comment: Hi @MarcusRenshaw -- %%time at the top of the cell was preventing me from assigning the output of my command. Nothing to do with networkx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the problem. `%%time` at the top of the cell was preventing my command's output being stored. This problem with `%%time` is described here: [link](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11659/). Removing it enabled the variable being assigned.